# Registers usage during compilation

Tags: cpu, cpu-registers, nios

I found information that general purpose registers r1-r23 and r26-r28 are used by the compiler to store local variables, but do they have any other purpose? Also which memory are this registers part of(cache/RAM)?
Finally what does global pointer gp in register r26 points to?

Comment: Which architecture are you considering?

Comment: NIOS II(SOC) from Intel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Also which memory are this registers part of(cache/RAM)?

Register are on-processors storage allowing a fast data transfer (2 reads/1 write per cycle). They store variables that can represent memory addresses, but, besides that, are completely unrelated to memory or cache.

> I found information that general purpose registers r1-r23 and r26-r28 are used by the compiler to store local variables, but do they have any other purpose?

Registers are use with respect to hardware or software conventions. Hardware conventions are related to the instruction set architecture. For instance, the `call` instruction transfers control to a subroutine and stores return address in register `r31 (ra)`. Very nasty things are likely to happen if you overwrite `r31` register by any mean without precautions. Software conventions are supposed to insure a proper behavior if used consistently within software. They indicate which register have special use, which need to be saved when context switching, etc. These conventions can be changed without hardware modifications, but doing so will probably require changes in several software tools (compiler, linker, loader, OS, ...).

> general purpose registers r1-r23 and r26-r28 are used by the compiler to store local variables

Actually, some registers are reserved.

`r1` is used by asm for macro expansion. (sw)

`r2-r7` are used by the compiler to pass arguments to functions or get return values. (sw)

`r24-r25` can only be used by exception handlers. (sw)

`r26-r28` hold different pointers (global, stack, frame) that are set either by the runtime or the compiler and cannot be modified by the programmer.(sw)

`r29-r31` are hw coded returns addresses for subprograms or interrupts/exceptions. (hw)

So only `r8-r23` can used by the compiler.

> but do they have any other purpose?

No, and that's why they can be freely used by the compiler or programmer.

> Finally what does global pointer in register r26 points to?

Accessing memory with load or stores have a based memory addressing. Effective address for `ldx` or `stx` (where 'x' is is b, bu, h, etc depending on data characteristics) is computed by adding a register and a 16 bits immediate. This only allows to go an an address within +/-32k of the content of register.

If the processor has the address of a var in a register (for instance the value returned by a `malloc`) the immediate allows to do a displacement to access fields in a struct, next array value, etc.

If the address is local or global, it must be computed by the program. Pointers registers are used to that purpose. Local  vars addresses are computed by adding an immediate to the stack pointer (`r27`or `sp`).

Addresses of global or static vars are computed by adding an integer to the global pointer (`r26` or `gp`).  Content of `gp` corresponds to the start of the memory data segment and is initialized by the loader just before program execution and must not be modified. The immediate displacement with respect to the start of data segment is computed by the linker when it defines memory layout.

Note that this only allows to access 64k memory because of the 16 bits immediate width. If the size of global/static variables exceeds this value and a var is not within this range, a couple of instructions are required to enter the 32 bits of the address of the var before the data transfer. With  `gp` this is not required and it is a way to provide a faster access to global variables.

Comment: thanks a lot, i found it very informative, does it mean that r8-r23 are used by compailer to allocate callee functions?

Comment: one more question, what kind of special use can be provided by registers?

Comment: Besides what was already mentioned (pointers to memory location, return addresses for subroutines/interrupts, passing functions arguments or return values, etc), in some architectures, general purpose registers can be used to hold the program counter (arm), ALU flags, etc.